# Galaxy Empire - Error 417 when logging in

Tags: technical-issues, galaxy-empire

I tried to open this game on my Android, click my name to log in, and keep getting 'Error code:417". Googling isn't helping. I am connected to my Work WiFi. What is this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that something on your network is blocking it from accessing the servers. After disconnecting from the Work WiFi connection, I could connect via LTE with no issues.